# VS Code is complaining "Git: maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My Git repo has tens of thousands of refs

```
$ git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format "%(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)" | wc -l
$ 174158
```

When I click on the branch icon in the Git explorer, I see this screenshot

[image]

I clicked on the Git log which switched me to the log window but nothing useful there.

I increased the log level to TRACE of Git inside VS Code settings but nothing more useful is coming out.

Nothing in the current release of VS Code allows us to limit refs based on time etc. Anyway I can get the actual command and the traceback of the error?

Comment: Can you try looking at the contents of VS Code's Git output log? (use this VS Code command to open it: `Git: Show Git Output`). It should show git commands that have been run and how long they took to complete. If you find info about what command it might be, add it to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

try to run `git remote prune origin`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33443567)

Comment: It solved the problem for me. I closed vscode, ran this command and restarted vscode, and the "maximum call stack exceeded" error went away. 
Not sure you have to close and reopen vscode, it may work without.